# Calling a page using a provider inside a bottom navigation bar in flutter

Tags: flutter, mvvm, provider

Am using a provider for each page in my flutter application like so :

```
class HolidayListState extends State<HolidayListView>{

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final vm = Provider.of<HolidayListViewModel>(context);

    if(vm.holidaysviews == null){
      return Align(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    }else if(vm.holidaysviews.isEmpty) {
      return Align(child: Text("No holidays found."));
    }else{

    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xfff0f0f0),

        body:SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 145),
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                  width: double.infinity,

                  child: ChangeNotifierProvider(
                    create: (_) => HolidayListViewModel(),
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: vm.holidaysviews.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {

                        final holiday = vm.holidaysviews[index];
                        final item = holiday.toString();
                        return Dismissible(
                          key: UniqueKey(),
                          background: Container(
                            alignment: AlignmentDirectional.centerEnd,
                            color: Colors.red,
                            child: Icon(
                              Icons.delete,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          ),
                          direction: DismissDirection.endToStart,
                          confirmDismiss:
                              (DismissDirection direction) async {
                            return await showDialog(
                              context: context,
                              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                return AlertDialog(
                                  title: const Text("Confirm"),
                                  content: const Text(
                                      "Are you sure you wish to delete this item?"),
                                  actions: <Widget>[
                                    FlatButton(
                                        onPressed: () async {
                                         await HolidayWebServices().deleteHoliday(holiday.id.toString());

                                          Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
                                        },
                                        child: const Text("DELETE")),
                                    FlatButton(
                                      onPressed: () =>
                                          Navigator.of(context).pop(false),
                                      child: const Text("CANCEL"),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                );
                              },
                            );
                          },
                          onDismissed: (direction) {
                            if (!mounted) {
                              setState(() {
                                vm.holidaysviews.removeAt(index);
                              });
                            }
                          },
                          child: Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                            width: double.infinity,
                            height: 110,
                            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                vertical: 10, horizontal: 20),
                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                vertical: 10, horizontal: 20),
                            child: Row(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                  width: 30,
                                  height: 30,
                                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 15),
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                                    border: Border.all(
                                        width: 3, color: Colors.deepPurple),
                                  ),
                                  child: Text(
                                    holiday.duration
                                        .toString(),
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Expanded(
                                  child: Column(
                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                    CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      ConditionalBuilder(
                                        condition:
                                        holiday.status ==
                                            "PENDING",
                                        builder: (context) {
                                          return Container(
                                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                              borderRadius:
                                              BorderRadius.circular(25),
                                              color: Colors.white,
                                            ),
                                            foregroundDecoration:
                                            BadgeDecoration(
                                              badgeColor: Colors.orange,
                                              badgeSize: 70,
                                              textSpan: TextSpan(
                                                text:holiday.status,
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                    color: Colors.white,
                                                    fontSize: 12),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          );
                                        },
                                      ),
                                      ConditionalBuilder(
                                        condition:
                                        holiday.status ==
                                            "ACCEPTED",
                                        builder: (context) {
                                          return Container(
                                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                              borderRadius:
                                              BorderRadius.circular(25),
                                              color: Colors.white,
                                            ),
                                            foregroundDecoration:
                                            BadgeDecoration(
                                              badgeColor: Colors.green,
                                              badgeSize: 70,
                                              textSpan: TextSpan(
                                                text: holiday.status,
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                    color: Colors.white,
                                                    fontSize: 12),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          );
                                        },
                                      ),
                                      ConditionalBuilder(
                                        condition:
                                        holiday.status ==
                                            "REFUSED",
                                        builder: (context) {
                                          return Container(
                                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                              borderRadius:
                                              BorderRadius.circular(25),
                                              color: Colors.white,
                                            ),
                                            foregroundDecoration:
                                            BadgeDecoration(
                                              badgeColor: Colors.red,
                                              badgeSize: 70,
                                              textSpan: TextSpan(
                                                text: holiday.status,
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                    color: Colors.white,
                                                    fontSize: 12),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          );
                                        },
                                      ),
                                      Row(
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          Icon(
                                            Icons.calendar_today,
                                            color: Colors.deepPurple,
                                            size: 20,
                                          ),
                                          Text(
                                              holiday.startDate,
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  color: primary,
                                                  fontSize: 13,
                                                  letterSpacing: .3)),

                                        ],
                                      ),
                                      SizedBox(
                                        height: 6,
                                      ),

                                      Row(
                                        children: <Widget>[

                                          Icon(
                                            Icons.calendar_today,
                                            color: Colors.deepPurple,
                                            size: 20,
                                          ),
                                          Text(holiday.endDate,
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  color: primary,
                                                  fontSize: 13,
                                                  letterSpacing: .3)),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                      SizedBox(
                                        height: 6,
                                      ),
                                      Row(
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          Icon(
                                            Icons.assignment,
                                            color: Colors.deepPurple,
                                            size: 20,
                                          ),
                                          SizedBox(
                                            width: 5,
                                          ),
                                          Text(holiday.type,
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  color: primary,
                                                  fontSize: 13,
                                                  letterSpacing: .3)),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        );

                       },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 140,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: primary,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30),
                          bottomRight: Radius.circular(30))),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          "Holidays",
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 24),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 110,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
              
            ),
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
          backgroundColor: kPrimaryColor,
          onPressed: () {


            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) {
                  return StepperDemo();
                },
              ),
            );
          },
        )
    );



  }}
}

class BadgeDecoration extends Decoration {
  final Color badgeColor;
  final double badgeSize;
  final TextSpan textSpan;

  const BadgeDecoration(
      {@required this.badgeColor,
        @required this.badgeSize,
        @required this.textSpan});

  @override
  BoxPainter createBoxPainter([onChanged]) =>
      _BadgePainter(badgeColor, badgeSize, textSpan);
}

class _BadgePainter extends BoxPainter {
  static const double BASELINE_SHIFT = 1;
  static const double CORNER_RADIUS = 4;
  final Color badgeColor;
  final double badgeSize;
  final TextSpan textSpan;

  _BadgePainter(this.badgeColor, this.badgeSize, this.textSpan);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Offset offset, ImageConfiguration configuration) {
    canvas.save();
    canvas.translate(
        offset.dx + configuration.size.width - badgeSize, offset.dy);
    canvas.drawPath(buildBadgePath(), getBadgePaint());
    // draw text
    final hyp = math.sqrt(badgeSize * badgeSize + badgeSize * badgeSize);
    final textPainter = TextPainter(
        text: textSpan,
        textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
        textAlign: TextAlign.center);
    textPainter.layout(minWidth: hyp, maxWidth: hyp);
    final halfHeight = textPainter.size.height / 2;
    final v = math.sqrt(halfHeight * halfHeight + halfHeight * halfHeight) +
        BASELINE_SHIFT;
    canvas.translate(v, -v);
    canvas.rotate(0.785398); // 45 degrees
    textPainter.paint(canvas, Offset.zero);
    canvas.restore();
  }

  Paint getBadgePaint() => Paint()
    ..isAntiAlias = true
    ..color = badgeColor;

  Path buildBadgePath() => Path.combine(
      PathOperation.difference,
      Path()
        ..addRRect(RRect.fromLTRBAndCorners(0, 0, badgeSize, badgeSize,
            topRight: Radius.circular(CORNER_RADIUS))),
      Path()
        ..lineTo(0, badgeSize)
        ..lineTo(badgeSize, badgeSize)
        ..close());
}
```

and I want to call the page in a navigation bar , right now this is the navigation bar page :

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:helium/views/holiday/holidayList.dart';
import 'package:helium/views/login/login_screen.dart';
import 'package:helium/views/profile/profile_home.dart';
import 'package:helium/views/time_tracking/time_tracking_home.dart';

class MainMenu extends StatefulWidget {
  
  @override
  _MainMenuState createState() => _MainMenuState();

  void signOut() {}
}

class _MainMenuState extends State<MainMenu> {
  PageController _pageController;
  int _page = 0;
  List icons = [
    Icons.home,
    Icons.event,
    Icons.beach_access_rounded

    // Icons.ac_unit,
  ];
  List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    Profile(),
    MyCalendarPage(),
    HolidayListView()
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              signOut();
            },
            icon: Icon(Icons.lock_open),
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: PageView(
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        controller: _pageController,
        onPageChanged: onPageChanged,
        children: _widgetOptions,
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: bottomMenu(),
      floatingActionButtonAnimator: FloatingActionButtonAnimator.scaling,
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,

    );
  }
  Widget bottomMenu(){
    return BottomAppBar(
      child: Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(width: 2),
          buildTabIcon(0),
          buildTabIcon(1),
          buildTabIcon(2),


          SizedBox(width: 2),
        ],
      ),
      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
    );
  }
  void navigationTapped(int page) {
    _pageController.jumpToPage(page);
  }





  signOut() {
    setState(() {
      widget.signOut();
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginScreen()),
      );
      print("signed out");
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // getPref();
    _pageController = PageController();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _pageController.dispose();
  }

  void onPageChanged(int page) {
    setState(() {
      this._page = page;
    });
  }

  buildTabIcon(int index) {
    return IconButton(
      icon: Icon(
        icons[index],
        size: 24.0,
      ),
      color: Colors.grey,

      //_page == index
          //? Theme.of(context).accentColor
          //: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption.color,
      onPressed: () => _pageController.jumpToPage(index),
    );

  }
}
```

apparently I have to call the provider somewhere in the bottom nav bar page but I don't know how to do it , right now am getting this error , so if anyone knows what seems to be wrong , I would appreciate so me help , here's the stack trace :

```
Error: Could not find the correct Provider<HolidayListViewModel> above this HolidayListView Widget

This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:

- You added a new provider in your `main.dart` and performed a hot-reload.
  To fix, perform a hot-restart.

- The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.

  Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route, then
  other routes will not be able to access that provider.

- You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.

  Make sure that HolidayListView is under your MultiProvider/Provider<HolidayListViewModel>.
  This usually happens when you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediately.

  For example, instead of:

  
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // Will throw a ProviderNotFoundError, because `context` is associated
      // to the widget that is the parent of `Provider<Example>`
      child: Text(context.watch<Example>()),
    ),
  }
  

  consider using `builder` like so:

  
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // we use `builder` to obtain a new `BuildContext` that has access to the provider
      builder: (context) {
        // No longer throws
        return Text(context.watch<Example>()),
      }
    ),
  }
```

Comment: Where is declared your `Provider<HolidayListViewModel>` ?

Comment: @FPerroch in a viewmodel page :  ``` 
class HolidayListViewModel extends ChangeNotifier{

List <HolidayViewModel> holidaysviews = List <HolidayViewModel>();
void populateHolidays () async{
  List<Holiday> holidays = await HolidayWebServices().fetchHoliday();
  this.holidaysviews= holidays.map((holiday) => HolidayViewModel(holiday:holiday)).toList();
  notifyListeners();


}



}```

Comment: Ok, but it has to be declared before you MaterialApp or Navigation widget to be accessible from your widget tree. check if it's the case

Comment: @FPerroch Thank you so much but can you explain further ? How do i declare it before the materialApp when i need it in the viewmodel page?

Comment: You've just to embed your material app in your Provider instance ;)

Comment: @FPerroch sorry for bothering u but am new to this whole provider thing , and am using more than just provider in my app can u please give me an example i'd be thankful

Comment: It's hard to explain here, but the error detail has enough info to help you